# bigQuery c#/Java - How to work with large result

Tags: java, c#-4.0, google-bigquery, google-api-java-client, google-api-dotnet-client

I am new to bigQuery, and I am trying to understand better the Large result concept.

I am trying to query over my Table with several select queries.
I am using C# with the Google API, using the Asynchronous method as described here:

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#asyncqueries

when I reach the LareResult limit - I get this error: "Table not found" - with the temporary table I created. (I think this might be a Bug?).

Any way - If I want to get this Large result I must set the "AllowLargeResult" flag with a destination table name, and the data will be created in a new table

**And then What? - How can I get these result?** If I query the new created table I still get large result. 
Is there a Way for me to understand if I got this limit without getting this exception?

**A working java/C# example will be appreciated.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End up using the Limit to do some sort of pagination.